# text field validation in html5 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML5 validaion , How can i check if Field contains only Text value

```
<form >
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>
```

Jquery validation :

```
if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) 
{
}
else
{
    alert('Invalid form , Enter All Values');
}
```

How to check field for only text value.

Comment: A text value? As opposed to what other sort or value? The value can only be a string.

Comment: it should not contain number or special character

Comment: Names **do** include numbers and "special" characters (whatever you mean by special in this case, someone's name probably includes it). http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ is worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `required and pattern attribute` like,

```
<form >
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,10}"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,10}"><br>
</form>
```

Read [required attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Techniques/HTML5/Using_the_required_attribute_to_indicate_a_required_input_field) and [custom-html5-form-validation](http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2012/11/21/creating-a-custom-html5-form-validation/)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4hCMM/)

Comment: need to check that it should not contain special character or number

Comment: how can i display specific error if fied is Not verified?? using my jquery alert function i am only printing  some Eroor. how can i print specific error that " teacher field contains number"

Comment: Use `title attribute` refer `custom-html5-form-validation` link from my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) 
    {
             var filter = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/; //regex to chk for only chars
        if (filter.test($("form")[0].val())) {
            return true;
        }
                }
                else
                {
                alert('Invalid form , Enter All Values');

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. Use `pattern` for your desire validation.

```
<form >
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname" pattern="[A-z]" /><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" pattern="[A-z]" /><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want some thing like this,

HTML5: `<input pattern="regexp">`

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z]" >
```

Javascript:

```
  var String = 'you text here';
  var Letters = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/.test(String);
```